# cAdvisor enable_metrics command not working in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, cadvisor

I'm using cAdvisor and Prometheus to monitor docker containers. I start the application using a `docker-compose.yml` file.

In the [cAdvisor docs](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/runtime_options.md), I read that the `--enable_metrics` and `--disable_metrics` flags can be used to select only a subset of metrics to monitor.
However, as soon as I supply any of these flags, cAdvisor appears to only monitor itself.

The --ignore_containers=cadvisor flag isn't working either, so I must be doing something wrong?

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
    - 9090:9090
    command:
    - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    volumes:
    - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:ro
    depends_on:
    - cadvisor
  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
    container_name: advisor
# also tried:
# command: "--enable_metrics=memory"
# command: --enable_metrics=memory
# and more...

   command:
      - --disable_metrics=accelerator,advtcp,app,cpu,cpuLoad,cpu_topology,cpuset,disk,diskIO,hugetlb,memory_numa,network,oom_event,percpu,perf_event,process,referenced_memory,resctrl,sched,tcp,udp
      - --enable_metrics=cpuLoad,memory,network
      - --ignore_containers=cadvisor
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
    - /:/rootfs:ro
    - /var/run:/var/run:rw
    - /sys:/sys:ro
    - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:to

   ... containers ...
```

EDIT:

I tried what user e0031374 suggested, and fixed the cAdvisor version to v0.47.1.
However, I noticed that as soon as I provide any command, the container exits in an unhealthy state. Without the command everything runs fine.

For example, when I add

```
    command: 
      - "--version"
```

`docker ps -a` shows:

```
5c4092450466   gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor             "/usr/bin/cadvisor -…"   24 seconds ago   Exited (0) 16 seconds ago
```

`docker container inspect 5c4092450466` shows:

```
...
Created": "2023-04-20T15:57:15.491743018Z",
        "Path": "/usr/bin/cadvisor",
        "Args": [
            "-logtostderr",
            "--version"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-04-20T15:57:22.532921383Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2023-04-20T15:57:22.726984392Z",
            "Health": {
                "Status": "unhealthy",
                "FailingStreak": 0,
                "Log": []
            }
        },
...
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running cadvisor with runtime option `command: "--version"` to check the version of the cadvisor image you are using

cadvisor may be below v0.41.0 even though latest version is specified. if so you may need to manually specify a later version like `image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:v0.47.0`

Comment: Thanks! I'm running `cAdvisor version v0.47.1 (7dfeea7d)`.
I noticed that if I do not provide any command, the container runs without issues. However, as soon as I try to add any command (even --version) the container exits in an unhealthy state. Do you have any ideas about what I could be doing wrong? I'll update my question to provide more context.

Comment: what does running `docker container logs <container_id>` say?

also have you tried using only `--enable_metrics=cpuLoad,memory,network` in command with `image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:v0.47.1`. leaving out any other command. since i dont think accelerator is supported in disable_metrics after [v0.46.1](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/pull/3206)

Comment: from the [docs](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/runtime_options.md#limiting-which-containers-are-monitored) and error log, i dont think `--ignore_containers` is a supported runtime option either

Answer (score 0):

**Enabling / Disabling metrics**

Inspect supported `cadvisor` flags with

```
docker run -it --rm gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:v0.47.2 -h
docker run -it --rm gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:v0.47.2 -h | grep 'enable_metrics' -A1
```

you get

```
  -enable_metrics metrics
        comma-separated list of metrics to be enabled. If set, overrides 'disable_metrics'. Options are advtcp,app,cpu,cpuLoad,cpu_topology,cpuset,disk,diskIO,hugetlb,memory,memory_numa,network,oom_event,percpu,perf_event,process,referenced_memory,resctrl,sched,tcp,udp.
```

the correct flag format is

```
-enable_metrics=<metrics_group_from_the_cadvisor_help>
```

(notice single dash). Single specific metrics cannot be enabled or disabled.

The correct `docker-compose` command format is

```
command:
  - '-enable_metrics=cpu,memory'
```

Do not use more than one `-enable_metrics` flags - only the last one is used.

After `cadvisor` deployment you can test if the desired metrics is indeed exposed ie.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8090/metrics | grep container_cpu_usage_seconds_total
```

**Ignoring specific containers**

`-ignore_containers` is not supported flag. Currently the only option is to label the containers and exclude them in the Prometheus scrape configuration by label.